# MacBook Pro: No feedback sound on changing volume and on mouse clicks

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I have a 13" mid 2012 MacBook Pro. I am not getting any sound on increasing/decreasing volume and on mouse clicks.

The MacBook has suddenly stopped making those click sounds and the volume button doesn't make that sound as well. My speakers are fine. I have recently upgraded my RAM.

What could possibly the issue be?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you please go to System Preferences → Sound → Sound Effects and check if Play feedback when volume is changed settings is enabled.

Comment: Also, please specify the version of macOS running on your MacBook Pro.

Comment: I'm using MacOS Mojave 10.14.3

Comment: Did you manage to check the setting as mentioned in the first comment?

Comment: Yes, I did. There's a different sound coming, not what used to come before. Is this because the sound is updated?

Comment: Yes. The sound has been updated starting with OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences → Sound → Sound Effects and make sure **Play user interface sound effects** and **Play feedback when volume is changed** are checked.

[image]

The sound clip played back when increasing/decreasing volume has been changed starting with OS X Yosemite and, thus, you will find it different from earlier versions of macOS.

Comment: This was my problem & solution. Thanks.
Does anyone know why my Mac decided to shut this feature off without my permission?  Some strange shortcut accidentally pressed? I've used this feature several times a day for the past 6 years.